# Finding the Delta of a Column within Pyspark Interactive Shell

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have this DataFrame:

```
DataFrame[visitors: int, beach: string, Date: date]
```

With the following data:

```
+-----------+-------------+--------+
|date       |beach        |visitors| 
+-----------+------------+---------+
|2020-03-02 |Bondi Beach |205      |
|2020-03-02 |Nissi Beach |218      |
|2020-03-03 |Bar Beach   |201      |
|2020-03-04 |Navagio     |102      |
|2020-03-04 |Champangne  |233      |
|2020-03-05 |Lighthouse  |500      |
|2020-03-06 |Mazo        |318      |
+-----------+------------+---------+
```

And I'm looking to find the delta of these columns using the data in the visitor's column.
Expected output:

```
+-----------+-------------+--------+-------+
|date       |beach        |visitors| Delta | 
+-----------+------------+---------+-------+
|2020-03-02 |Bondi Beach |205      |-13    | (205-218)
|2020-03-02 |Nissi Beach |218      |17     | (218-201)
|2020-03-03 |Bar Beach   |201      |99     | (201-102)
|2020-03-04 |Navagio     |102      |-131   | (102-233)
|2020-03-04 |Champangne  |233      |-267   | (233-500)
|2020-03-05 |Lighthouse  |500      |182    | (500-318)
|2020-03-06 |Mazo        |318      |318    | (318-0)
+-----------+------------+---------+-------+
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `lead` function for your problem. Since the `lead` of the last row is `null`, I'm using the `coalesce` function to replace `nulls` with the visitors' column.

```
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

w=Window().orderBy("date")

df.withColumn("delta", col("visitors") - lead("visitors").over(w))\
    .withColumn('delta', coalesce('delta', 'visitors')).show()

+----------+-----------+--------+-----+
|      date|      beach|visitors|delta|
+----------+-----------+--------+-----+
|2020-03-02|Bondi Beach|     205|  -13|
|2020-03-02|Nissi Beach|     218|   17|
|2020-03-03|  Bar Beach|     201|   99|
|2020-03-04|    Navagio|     102| -131|
|2020-03-04| Champangne|     233| -267|
|2020-03-05| Lighthouse|     500|  182|
|2020-03-06|       Mazo|     318|  318|
+----------+-----------+--------+-----+
```

**Note:** I'm just ordering by the `date` field. It will be good to have another column like an id to include in the order by clause so that the order is maintained. Also, using a window without partitions can have a performance impact.